# Copying files from one server to other via erlang code

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, scp, mnesia

I want to copy files from one server(Say `A`) to other(Say `B`).Scenerio is->User sends me a file(video,zip or photo) in binary.I write this to `/var/www/myfolder` of `A`.Now in next step i want this to be copied at `B`.I used `os:cmd(scp ----)` command.But it gives  error like->

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

I think it is asking for password of B.How  can i  configure password in `scp` command or is there any other method to do this in erlang?

Comment: If you have valid a ssh-key, and the public part of this ssh-key is on the server Bs authorized_keys list, there should be no problem. look at: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/ssh-with-keys/ for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use Erlang File I/O if you have both servers connected using erlang distribution protocol. (You can do it over TCP or UDP or any other networking as well but it is more complicated).

Let's demonstrate it using two "servers" running on the same machine (it works same over a network, but you have to connect them properly). First we make directory for each server and content of file `foo` to transfer:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ echo Hello World > a/foo
```

Let's start two servers each in a different directory:

```
$ cd a
a$ erl -sname a
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
(a@hynek-notebook)1>
```

and the second server in a different console:

```
$ cd b
b$ erl -sname b
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
(b@hynek-notebook)1>
```

Now we check there is nothing on the `b` server yet:

```
(b@hynek-notebook)1> ls().
ok
(b@hynek-notebook)2>
```

Now we can connect nodes, check if they are connected and read the file `foo`.

```
(a@hynek-notebook)1> net_kernel:connect('b@hynek-notebook').
true
(a@hynek-notebook)2> net_adm:ping('b@hynek-notebook').
pong
(a@hynek-notebook)3> ls().
foo
ok
(a@hynek-notebook)4> {ok, Bin} = file:read_file("foo").
{ok,<<"Hello World\n">>}
(a@hynek-notebook)5>
```

And write file to server `b` using `rpc:call/4`:

```
(a@hynek-notebook)5> rpc:call('b@hynek-notebook', file, write_file, ["bar", Bin]).
ok
(a@hynek-notebook)6>
```

Check the result on the server `b`:

```
(b@hynek-notebook)2> ls().
bar
ok
(b@hynek-notebook)3> {ok, Bin} = file:read_file("bar").
{ok,<<"Hello World\n">>}
(b@hynek-notebook)4>
```

For bigger files, you should not transfer a whole file in the one big binary. Unfortunately, you need at least some code support from sending or receiving side. You can transfer file handler from one node to another but the process which calls `file:open/2` has to keep running. It is reason you can't just use `{ok, FH} = rpc:call(Node, file, open, [FN, [write]]).` It's a bummer. One way is to make a very simple server which opens a file and keeps running.

```
(b@hynek-notebook)4> Self = self().
<0.40.0>
(b@hynek-notebook)5> F = fun() -> Self ! file:open("baz", [write]), receive close -> ok end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.54118792>
(b@hynek-notebook)6> FS = spawn_link('a@hynek-notebook', F).
<7329.48.0>
(b@hynek-notebook)7> {ok, FH} = receive X -> X end.
{ok,<7329.49.0>}
(b@hynek-notebook)8> file:write(FH, Bin).
ok
(b@hynek-notebook)9> FS ! close.
close
(b@hynek-notebook)10>
```

And we expect file `baz` with proper content on the server `a`:

```
(a@hynek-notebook)6> ls().
baz     foo
ok
(a@hynek-notebook)7> {ok, _} = file:read_file("baz").
{ok,<<"Hello World\n">>}
(a@hynek-notebook)8>
```

The other option is to write a server which will receive blocks and write them instead of sending a file handler. And there are many other options how to do it using direct TCP connection using HTTP or your own protocol and using `file:send_file/2,5` and many other ways.